# How to Add Spark Dataframe to a batch using PreparedStatement without Iterating through the Rows

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, database-connection, prepared-statement

Currently i am using below logic to perform a batch Insert for a spark dataframe i am creating after reading real time streaming data from kafka topic using Kafka Spark streaming APIs. This data i need to load into a DB2 staging table based on the batch size.
The data size is thousand transactions per second that i am consuming from the topic.

```
Class DF_Creation{
.
DB2_CLASS.insert(DB2_Table, final_dataframe, batchSize);
.
}

Class DB2_CLASS{
.
public static void insert(String DB2_Table, Dataset<Row> final_dataframe, int batchSize){
CREATE DB2 Connection..Connection conn = ......
CREATE STATEMENT Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
String truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE DB2_Table IMMEDIATE";
stmt.execute(truncate);
final_dataframe.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>) rows -> {
       String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " + DB2_Table + " (COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ";
       try (Connection conn = CREATE DB2 Connection
             PreparedStatement insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery)) {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            try{
                            int cnt = 0;
                            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                            int idx = 0;
                            Row row = rows.next();
                    insertStmt.setString(++idx, row.getAs("COL1"));
                    insertStmt.setString(++idx, row.getAs("COL2"));
                    insertStmt.setString(++idx, row.getAs("COL3"));
                        insertStmt.addBatch();
                                            cnt++;
                    if (cnt >= batchSize) {
                        insertStmt.executeBatch();
                        conn.commit();
                        insertStmt.clearBatch();
                        cnt = 0;
                    }
                        }}catch{..}
        }
    }
}}
```

This is impacting the performance of the spark job as i am iterating through each of the rows, reading each of the columns, to create the batch.
Is there any way to create a batch directly, without iterating through the rows and columns.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can straightaway write your dataframe to the destination table through the JDBC option in the spark dataframe writer. There is no longer the requirement of creating a prepared statement while iterating through the whole dataframe row by row. Spark handles all that internally.

You can write:

```
import com.ibm.db2.jcc._

val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:db2://host:port/database_name"

val db2Properties = new Properties()

final_dataframe.write.mode("append").option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").jdbc(jdbcUrl, table = "table_name", db2Properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option "batchsize" while writing dataframe to any RDBMS using df.write(). You can use that while writing data in batch to your table.